# npm install command not working with proxy

Tags: angular, npm-install

I need to install angular cli in my windows system.But whenvever  i try to install it using the npm install command i am getting an error.I am using a proxy network of my college.[i have atttched the scren shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PwPm.png)

Comment: Please try to copy the error message as text into your question. A screenshot of an error message is considered bad, because it does not allow people to find this question by typing the message in a search engine. (among other reasons). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

Try below steps

1. `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Then set npm to run with http, instead of https:

2. `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Then I install packages using this syntax:

3. `npm --proxy http://username:password@cacheaddress.com.br:80 \ install packagename`

> Skip the username:password part if proxy doesn't require you to
>   authenticate
>
> You may get NPM to work behind a proxy by setting BOTH HTTP_PROXY and
>   HTTPS_PROXY environment variables, then issuing normally the command
>   `npm install express` (for example)

To know more about running npm command behind corporate proxy [click here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/)

Answer (score 0):

run those commands as:

1 .npm config set strict-ssl false
Then set npm to run with http, instead of https:

2 . npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
Then I install packages using this syntax:

3. npm --proxy http://username:password@cacheaddress.com.br:80 \
   install packagename
   Skip the username:password part if proxy doesn't require you to authenticate

   You may get NPM to work behind a proxy by setting BOTH HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables, then issuing normally the command npm install express

Good Luck